# How to draw digital signal in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface

I need to draw digital signal and be able to move each part of the lines in WPF.

As shown in picture below the arrows indicate to which direction the part of the line can be moved. Clicking and dragging the "clickable area" will move the whole square left or right.

[image]

I thought couple of ways to do it:

1. `Polyline` object. But I cannot control each part of the line.
2. `Line` object. On each change all lines should adjust their locations. Hard to control "clickable area". Maybe also complicated.
3. `Border` object. Each section will actually be a border which will show/hide appropriate border side. I'm not sure how easy to make movable sides of the border.
4. Other options...

My question is, what is the most correct way to start doing it?

Comment: I'm thinking I would start with Rectangles and collect a set of points from which a GraphicsPath is plotted. That is my suggestion on where to start. Haven't done anything like this before.

Comment: If I were you, I'd edit your question to be less subjective and more practical, unless you want it to be closed for being *primarily opinion based*.

Comment: @Sheridan, what do you suggest? "How to draw digital..." is better?

Comment: You can create a mixed object which consists of lines and a rectangle the clickable area.

Comment: I like the Border or Rect idea, one for each pulse. not sure why you want to raise/lower your high and low of digital signal. When you raise teh low, do you raise all the lows? You can place the Border by setting it's XY on the Canvas and the width of the pulse is the width of the Border.

Comment: @kenny, the idea of raise/lower is create/remove pulse. When you lower it turns to be 0, when you raise it creates narrow pulse and than you can move it left/right to control its width. So, only the pulse that is lowered is affected. I meant to use `Canvas` to place `Border` if I would choose Border/Option:)

Comment: @McGarnagle, are u suggesting to represent each pulse as `Path` so it would be dragable?

Comment: Actually I was thinking one path for the whole thing -- each pulse would be a segment in the PathGeometry.  (I don't know how feasible this is, as my company blocks images, so I can't see the figure you posted.)

Comment: @McGarnagle, the graph is `___|----|_____|---|_____`. I need to be able to move the sides of the pulse (|) and also be able to click inside the pulse. I can't see how it can be done with segment in `PathGeometry`. The segment is not clickable. The only way I can see doing it with path is **lots of Paths with line segment in each**

Comment: @theateist well, couldn't you use one path with one click handler, then map the click to the appropriate segment?  That may add some complexity, I'm not sure.  One benefit of using Path is that if you move the pulse point, the connected part will move automatically.

Comment: @McGarnagle, I'm not sure that you can know on which segment you've clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to consider...

- a `Thumb` is a good control to start your draggable things from, as it already provides proper events you can handle to move it. By templating it you can give it any shape you like.
- you may get draggable lines for free through clever use of a `Grid` and appropriately placed grid splitters. If that doesn't work then 4 rectangles could work well. You put them in a `DockingPanel` with placement top, left, right and the last one fill, and you have enough primitives to react to all desired events.

Comment: The `Thumb` really helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can code this up if you like, but here is how I would do it...

Maintain a list of pair<  x_position,  height) >  Sort it by X.  Do this in a custom control.

Draw that in a for loop.  Determine clicks by hunting through the list.  Handle some mouse drags, update screen.

The for loop would look at mylist[i] and mylist[i+1].  Draw rectangle using that info.

I don't normally code in WPF, but I can figure it out in a half hour if you'd like.

Here is some code.............  Add code to namespace, build then add component to form:

```
 public class Pair
{
    public Pair()
    {
    }

    public Pair(float first, float second)
    {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }

    public float First { get; set; }
    public float Second { get; set; }
};

public class ImageButton :  FrameworkElement
{
    List<Pair> items;
    Boolean dragDown = false;
    bool dragVert = false;
    int dragSeg = -1;


    public ImageButton()  {
        items = new List<Pair>();
        items.Add(new Pair(0, 0));
        items.Add(new Pair(40, 40));
        items.Add(new Pair(60, 0));
        items.Add(new Pair(100, 20));
        items.Add(new Pair(115, 0));
        items.Add(new Pair(185, 20));
        items.Add(new Pair(215, 0));
        items.Add(new Pair(300, 0));

    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int seg;
        bool vert;

        if (getSegment(e.GetPosition(this).X, e.GetPosition(this).Y, out seg, out vert))
        {
            dragDown = true;
            dragSeg = seg;
            dragVert = vert;
            //We are dragging now
        }

        base.OnMouseDown(e);
    }
    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        dragDown = false;
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        double basey = RenderSize.Height - 10;

        int seg;
        bool vert;
        if (!dragDown)
        {

            if (getSegment(e.GetPosition(this).X, e.GetPosition(this).Y, out seg, out vert))
            {
                if (vert)
                {
                    Cursor = Cursors.SizeWE;
                }
                else
                {
                    Cursor = Cursors.SizeNS;
                };

            }
            else
            {
                Cursor = Cursors.No;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //Must be dragging.
            if (dragVert)
            {
                //This will change the X position of the segment...........
                items[dragSeg].First = (int) e.GetPosition(this).X;
                InvalidateVisual();
            }
            else
            {
                items[dragSeg].Second = (int)(basey - ((int)e.GetPosition(this).Y));
                //Change vertical
                InvalidateVisual();
            }
        }
        base.OnMouseMove(e);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        Brush b = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(40,40,40));
        dc.DrawRectangle(b, new Pen(b, 2), new Rect(0, 0, this.RenderSize.Width, RenderSize.Height));
        Pen p = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(240, 240, 240)), 2);
        double basey = RenderSize.Height - 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count-1; i++)
        {
            Brush br = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(240, 40, 40));
            Rect t = new Rect(items[i].First,basey-items[i].Second, items[i+1].First-items[i].First,items[i].Second);
            dc.DrawRectangle(br, p, t);
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns if over a segment, and how.  
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x"></param>
    /// <param name="y"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    bool getSegment(double x, double y, out int index, out bool vert)
    {
        double basey = RenderSize.Height - 10;
        index = 0;
        vert = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            //Check for vertical section going up
            if ((x >= (items[i].First - 3)) && ( x <= (items[i].First + 3))) {
                // x is hovering close to segment, check Y
                if ((y < (basey)) && (y>=(basey-items[i].Second))) {
                    index = i;
                    vert = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            //Check vertical going down.
            if ((x >= (items[i + 1].First - 3)) && (x <= (items[i + 1].First + 3)))
            {
                if ((y < (basey)) && (y >= (basey - items[i].Second)))
                {
                    index = i+1;
                    vert = true;
                    return true;
                }
            }

            //In the middle section
            if ((x >= (items[i].First) && (x <= (items[i+1].First)))) {
                //Check for close to line seg.
                if ((y < (basey - items[i].Second + 3)) && (y > (basey - items[i].Second - 3)))
                {
                    index = i;
                    vert = false;
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

When dragging the segments, don't overlap them - I didn't code it for that.  But this allows seeing the signal, and moving the signal.

[image: Sample of provided component]

After resizing with the mouse:

[image]

PS: I made no attempt to optimize or make any attempt at production code, just slammed it out for you.